# Using enum property in a custom workflow activity

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm writing a custom workflow activity and would like to have some properties that are based on enums. However, I'm getting an error that seems to indicate that this isn't supported. So, first question, how would I setup a property that allowed the user of the workflow activity to select from a set of choices?

And second, what types are allowed in a custom workflow activity (dependency properties that are available within the workflow designer)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [CRM Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156682.aspx) are supported in these activities.  So string, CrmMoney, CrmBoolean, Lookup, etc.  Unfortunately you can't provide your user with a drop-down of options.  About the best you could do would be to put those options in a table and use a lookup for the user to choose from.

"[Adding Metdata to the Custom Workflow Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151141.aspx)", from the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. On the CRM Types page, it indicates that a picklist can be used. Is this really possible? If so, how do you configure it so it actually has some options available?

Comment: Not sure I've tried a picklist.  I suppose you could see the example on that page <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677093.aspx#v4d0_sp4438r_inputparameterpicklist> making sure to use the metadata tag:  [CrmAttributeTarget("account", "industrycode")] to see if it shows up as you expect in the workflow activity.